# ¿Por que no se validan los campos? JQuery Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Estoy utilizando  [jQUERY Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/) en uno de mis formularios de ingreso,al pasar de un campo a otro, se valida la longitud de los caracteres correctamente, sin embargo al presionar el botón, el formulario no es validado, aunque los campos se encuentren en blanco. Según la documentación se debe de utilizar el siguiente código, pero este no funciona. Curiosamente si le quito el id="btn_ingresar" al botón, si valida los campos del formulario. Estoy utilizando AJAX para el envió de datos.

```
$("#myform").validate({
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    $(form).ajaxSubmit();
  }
});
```

Formulario

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_nuevo" name="modal_nuevo"  role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header bg-blue">
          <h5 class="modal-title text-info" id="myModalLabel">Agregar Tipo de Profesional</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body m-3">
         <p>Por favor ingrese la información solicitada en este cuadro para crear un nuevo tipo de profesional.</p>
          <form id="agregar_profesional" name="agregar_profesional">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label">Código</label>
                  <input  type="text"  class="form-control" id="id" name="id" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label class=" control-label">Descripción</label>
                  <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="tipo" name="tipo" required>
              </div>
      </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="mbtnCerrarModal" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
          <input class="btn btn-info ml-3" type="submit" value="Guardar"  id="btn_ingresar">
    </div>
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $("#agregar_profesional").validate({

    rules: {
    id: { required: true, minlength: 2},
    tipo: { required: true, minlength: 2}
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
    $(form).ajaxSubmit();
  }

  });

$("#btn_ingresar").click(function(e){
     $("#agregar_profesional").validate();
    e.preventDefault();
    var _form = $("#agregar_profesional").serialize();
    console.log("form:\n", _form);
    $.ajax({

    url: "<?=base_url();?>profesionales_tipos/agregar/", type: 'post', data: _form,
    success: function(response) {
         console.log("response modal new :\n", response);
           $("#modal_nuevo").modal('hide');
           $("#modal_confirmar").modal('show');
           $('#tblProfesionales').DataTable().ajax.reload();
           $("#id").val("");
           $("#tipo").val("");


       }
    });
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero en el formulario quita el `type="submit"` del botón que tiene el `id="btn_ingresar"`

Después en el código Javascript debería funcionar algo así

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

  var validar_formulario = $("#agregar_profesional").validate({

    rules: {
    id: { required: true, minlength: 2},
    tipo: { required: true, minlength: 2}
    }

  });

$("#btn_ingresar").click(function(e){

    if (validar_formulario.form()) //asi se comprueba si el form esta validado o no
    {       
        var _form = $("#agregar_profesional").serialize();
        console.log("form:\n", _form);
        $.ajax({

        url: "<?=base_url();?>profesionales_tipos/agregar/", type: 'post', data: _form,
        success: function(response) {
             console.log("response modal new :\n", response);
               $("#modal_nuevo").modal('hide');
               $("#modal_confirmar").modal('show');
               $('#tblProfesionales').DataTable().ajax.reload();
               $("#id").val("");
               $("#tipo").val("");


           }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        //ingresa todo lo que quieras aqui con relacion a que el form no se ha validado de manera correcta :)
    }
});
});
```

Si te fijas hago una comprobacion del formulario y esto se encuentra en la documentación del link que dejaste al principio :)

https://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.form/

Edit: no estoy seguro de esto pero al aplicar nuevamente el codigo`$("#agregar_profesional").validate();` `luego del $("#btn_ingresar").click` reiniciaria los filtros

Comment: Gracias amigo me funciono, me confundí de como usarlo con tantas descripciones, como usaba ajax, pensé que debía de ser como puse más arriba    submitHandler: function(form) {
    $(form).ajaxSubmit();
  }  o algo si.

Comment: De nada, a mi igual me confundió en esa parte un poco ya que también lo uso con ajax, pero fue la mejor solución que encontré, ya que se puede combinar con otros validadores que devuelvan estados en el if

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

El id de tu form es "`agregar_profesional`", no "`myform`". 
Y parece que tienes errores de etiquetas.

Comment: Vee bien el javascript hahha